# Facebook Login stopped working in hauth codeigniter

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter, hybridauth

I have a facebook app version 2.6, and i use this app for login with facebook in my codeigniter project with hybridauth library, everything works fine but suddenly it stopped working.

it gives following error :

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Authentication failed! Facebook returned an invalid user id.' in /home/kevala/public_html/mynursing/application/third_party/hybridauth/Hybrid/Providers/Facebook.php:89 Stack trace: #0 /home/kevala/public_html/mynursing/application/third_party/hybridauth/Hybrid/Endpoint.php(175): Hybrid_Providers_Facebook->loginFinish() #1 /home/kevala/public_html/mynursing/application/third_party/hybridauth/Hybrid/Endpoint.php(56): Hybrid_Endpoint::processAuthDone() #2 /home/kevala/public_html/mynursing/application/third_party/hybridauth/index.php(15): Hybrid_Endpoint::process() #3 /home/kevala/public_html/mynursing/application/modules/client/hauth/controllers/hauth.php(429): require_once('/home/kevala/pu...') #4 [internal function]: HAuth->endpoint() #5 /home/kevala/public_html/mynursing/system/core/CodeIgniter.php(359): call_user_func_array(Array, Array) #6 /home/kevala/public_html/mynursing/index.php(202): require_once('/home/kevala/pu...') #7 {main} Next exception 'Exception' in /home/kevala/public_html/mynursing/application/third_party/hybridauth/Hybrid/Auth.php on line 147
```

I searched for this issue and got so many results like

set in base_facebook.php

```
public static $CURL_OPTS = array(
    CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 10,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 60,
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => 'facebook-php-3.2',
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false,
  );
```

I tried this all but not succeeded :(

Can any one help for this? Please....

Comment: The Facebook PHP SDK v3 is way outdated; especially it is not prepared for the change in access token return format that occurred with API v2.4. (Are you sure you have actually been using 2.6? API v2.3 was shut down a few days ago, so if this “suddenly” stopped working, it would make much more sense that you were using 2.3)

Comment: Thanks @CBroe . This saved me, i have changed Facebook PHP SDK v5 and works great.